# SQL merge table and group by

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm not very good in SQL stuff, so I hope someone can explain this issue to me (and help me solve it)

I have a table;

```
++++++++++++++++++++
|  ID  |  Minutes  |
++++++++++++++++++++
| 1012 |    15     |
| 1012 |    25     |
| 1015 |    45     |
| 1016 |    10     |
| 1016 |    50     |
++++++++++++++++++++
```

And I want to achieve, that the table will be transferred, so every ID is unique, but the minutes are added up and it then looks like this:

```
++++++++++++++++++++
|  ID  |  Minutes  |
++++++++++++++++++++
| 1012 |    40     |
| 1015 |    45     |
| 1016 |    60     |
++++++++++++++++++++
```

The table is a view of the original table, the calculation of the minutes is done with "DATEDIFF" - probably this will help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Sum(Minutes)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Not necessary, I can figure that out myself ;-)